# Using postman for Giphy API Get request but comes back with no data

Tags: rest, api, get, postman, giphy

Like the title says, I'm trying to do a GET request to the Search endpoint of Giphy's API, but it comes back with an empty data array.  Is there anything I'm doing wrong?  I've made sure the API key is correct since it works for the 'trending' and 'random' endpoints.

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGKTC.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your screenshot, it looks like you've entered the `api_key` and `q` as **Headers**.

Instead, you should submit this information as **Request Parameters**. If you click the Params button, you'll expand a similar looking key-value editor where you can enter the parameters.

[image: screenshot of request parameters]